# Spring AOP with anonymous inner classes

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I use some anonymous inner classes like

```
foo(){
      A a = new A(arg1){   //it isn't spring bean yet
           public Smt bar(){
                return new Smt();
           }
      }
 }
```

And now I want add some [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) wrapping for this class. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // it isn't spring bean yet

I guess that implies that it will at some time be a spring bean? Then just use [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). It should work equally well on anonymous inner classes. After all they have names and packages just like any other class.

If not, you will probably have to use aspectj compiling or loadtime weaving.

Comment: P.Floyd - seanizer : Thanks. Yes, It will be spring been, probably. But I couldn't be anonymous inner classes, could it?